# Javadoc private methods

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin, doclet

I've developed my own Doclet to generate csv from Java classes.
I need to launch this Doclet about many projects and I can't edit POM files.
So I'm running using terminal:

```
mvn -DuseStandardDocletOptions=false
-Ddoclet=com.sadiel.gescontrata.lector.leeclases.LectorDoclet
-DdocletPath=C:\LeeClases.jar javadoc:javadoc
```

I need to generate documentation for Private methods, so I have try to add **-Dprivate** but this not works.

Somebody have any idea about what can I do?

Thanks,
Iván.

Comment: Did you try the `show` user property? Like: `mvn ... -Dshow=private`. See here for the documentation: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`private`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#private) is a `Javadoc` option. Maven just doesn't expose a property under the same name.

Try specifying the `show` user property. Like:

`mvn ... -Dshow=private`

See here for the documentation of this property: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#show